# Converting one long row of customer information into columns that are separated by blank row

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, transpose

I have 2500 rows of customer information in excel not all customers have the same amount of information (some have 6 lines, others 5, some 7 but they all are separated with a blank row. Is there a way to use the blank row as a separator for each different customer?

[this is what is looks like in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Zmm.png)

[this is what I would like it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaRRk.png)

Comment: Do you want to create a script to fix it for you? (in that case, what language?). You could do it [manually](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12366/convert-a-row-to-a-column-in-excel-the-easy-way/) ;) Please explain if you only want to use Excel functions or if you could use some other method

Comment: Hi, if it was in another language what program would I need to use it? I really have no preference how it gets done... just hoping I do not need to fix line by line 2500 times... =)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A1 and B1 are blank (A2 contains `North` etc) and output to be in ColumnsC:I, please put in B2 and copy down to suit:

```
=IF(A1="",1,B1+1)
```

This should allow you to filter by the each of the values in turn and copy to wherever these suit, while also being fairly easy to adjust if necessary.

However, if that identifies the lines for each 'set' suitably, you might then put in C1 and copy across to I1:

```
 =IF(AND(COLUMN()-2<MAX($B1:$B9),ISBLANK($A1)),OFFSET($A1,COLUMN()-2,0),"")
```

Then copy C1:I1 down to suit.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried this and I must be doing something wrong... the first one just puts 1 2 3 4 5 down the C1 column the other one just copies the first line over and over again....  =(

Comment: Hi, So as you can see from the this is what is look like image... I added a blank row in 1. I then added  =IF(A1="",1,B1+1) in B2 is that correct? When I do that inside B2 the number 1 shows up inside B2.

Comment: There are many things I'm very good at, Excel lis clearly not one of them.

Would you reply to this email address and let me send you the file? I know that is alot to ask and I totally understand if not.  

davidmeneo@icloud.com